# Wordpress single-post-type template not displaying post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a theme with two custom post types, sermons, and members. I also have permalinks set to postname.

At first, single.php would catch general blog posts, as well as members, but not sermons... it would only display the index.php file.

After some research, I found resetting (saving) permalinks would reset them. This sort of worked by now catching the member custom posts, but only to display index.php for sermons.

this is how I call them...

```
// Custom Post types for Sermons
add_action('init', 'sermons');

function sermons() {
  $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
       'name' => __( 'Sermons' ),
       'singular_name' => __( 'Sermons' ),
       'add_new' => __( 'Add Sermon' ),
       'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Sermon' ),
       'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Sermon' ),
       'new_item' => __( 'Add Sermon' ),
       'view_item' => __( 'View Sermon' ),
       'search_items' => __( 'Search Sermons' ),
       'not_found' => __( 'No Home Sermons found' ),
       'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Sermons found in trash' )
   ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    // 'menu_icon' => WP_CONTENT_URL . '/themes/####/images/home-widget.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
    'has_archive' => true
  );

  register_post_type('sermons',$args);
}

// Custom Post types for Members
add_action('init', 'members');

function members() {
  $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
       'name' => __( 'Members' ),
       'singular_name' => __( 'Members' ),
       'add_new' => __( 'Add Member' ),
       'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Member' ),
       'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Member' ),
       'new_item' => __( 'Add Member' ),
       'view_item' => __( 'View Member' ),
       'search_items' => __( 'Search Members' ),
       'not_found' => __( 'No Home Members found' ),
       'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Members found in trash' )
   ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    // 'menu_icon' => WP_CONTENT_URL . '/themes/####/images/home-widget.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
    'has_archive' => true
  );

  register_post_type('members',$args);
}
```

I have tried single-sermons.php and single-members.php, neither seem to work. Is it the way I registered each custom post type that is breaking this?

**** EDIT ****
Removed `'rewrite' => true` from $args, and everything is fine, but I'd much rather have SEO friendly urls.

**** EDIT ****
Fixed it... apparently, removing `'rewrite' => true` in the args, refreshing the permalinks, and adding `'rewrite' => true` again, did the trick.

Comment: Just wondering if setting 'publicly_queryable' => true, as an argument helps. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments . How about if you set up single-sermons.php and single-members.php templates?

Comment: yes, tried that. It wouldn't render for some reason. I will try your suggestion though. Thanks alot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should do a `flush_rewrite_rules()` after you've created your custom post types, this will refresh the permalink structure for you.

Just add `flush_rewrite_rules()` after your `register_post_type()` function.

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: It worked, by doing what it was supposed to. But it also reverted me to the original problem I had.

Comment: I doubt the problem you were having is in the code above, I don't see anything unusual

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it... apparently, removing `'rewrite' => true` in the args, refreshing the permalinks, and adding `'rewrite' => true` again, does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Re-saving Permalinks worked for me.  (Settings -> Permalinks -> SAVE).

Comment: I mentioned in the question that saving the permalinks didn't completely solve the issue. mary louise parker codes??

Comment: I know, but  removing 'rewrite' => true didn't work for me, so the permalinks fix may work for somebody else with the same scenario. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Setting `publicly_queryable => true` fixed my problem.